# Comparar una cadena con una respuesta AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un script de ajax el cual va y consulta en un php una BD mysql, si hay un registro devuelvo un echo "exito"; y si no "sin exito";

```
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dispositivos WHERE serie ='$serial'"));
if($total==0){
    echo "sin exito";
}else
{
  $sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM dispositivos WHERE serie ='$serial'");
  echo "exito"; 
}
```

este éxito o sin éxito lo guardo en

```
var respuesta = ajax.responseText
```

si hago un alert(respuesta);

efectivamente me muestra exito o sin exito dependiendo del resultado del PHP, por lo cual sé que hasta aquí todo está bien

lo que necesito es hacer más cosas si es un éxito, por lo cual hice un

```
if(respuesta=="exito")
    {
      // cosas que voy a hacer
    }
```

he aquí el problema, no entra al if, a pesar de ser "exito" lo pasa de largo, ya probé con = y con ==

no sé si es que no puedo comparar una variable con una cadena pero pues se supone que la variable tiene una cadena por lo cual si podría.

Comment: Está extraño lo que comentas, si la respuesta realmente tiene `exito` deberías poder compararlo como mencionas. Necesitaríamos ver más código para buscar el problema, como la parte php que devuelve el mensaje.

Comment: No veo problemas en el código. :/  Se me ocurre ejecutar este alert: `alert("---"+respuesta+"---");` para verificar si `respuesta` viene correctamente sin ningún espacio que pudiera haberse agregado en alguna parte del php.

Comment: ¿ Te importaría mostrar el código **Javascript** completo ? ¿ Dices que el error se produce en una función de respuesta a un AJAX ?

Comment: Muestra el codigo con el que haces la peticion al servidor para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Para estar seguro yo utilizaría el operador '===' para hacer una comparación de cadenas de manera estricta así:

```
if(respuesta === "exito") {
   // cosas que voy a hacer
}
```

El operador de == es menos estricto y de hecho esta comparando dos objetos, funcionaria si haces algo como esto:

```
if(new String(respuesta).valueOf() == new String("exito").valueOf()) {
   // cosas que voy a hacer
}
```

Exitos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `trim` es para eliminar los espacios en blanco:

```
if(respuesta.trim() === "exito") {
   // cosas que voy a hacer
}
```